# flask delete function – deleting a row from sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm struggling a bit to implement a delete function on flask based blog. I've searched for the relevant posts here and tried to combine the comments together but still it's not working.. It seems if I run the code the entry id doesn't go through to the url. It gives me 'page not found' error. Would be great to get help as to why this happens!

This is my py:

```
@app.route('/delete_entry/<entry_id>', methods=['POST'])
def delete_entry():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    db = get_db()
    db.execute('delete from entries where id=' + entry_id)
    db.commit()
    flash('Entry deleted')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
```

and this is my show_entries py:

```
    {% extends "layout.html" %}
    {% block body %}
      {% if session.logged_in %}
        <form action="{{ url_for('add_entry') }}" method=post class=add-entry>
          <dl>
            <dt>Title:
            <dd><input type=text size=30 name=title>
            <dt>Text:
            <dd><textarea name=text rows=5 cols=40></textarea>
            <dd><input type=submit value=Share>
          </dl>
        </form>

      {% endif %}
      <ul class=entries>
      {% for entry in entries %}
        <li><h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2><h6>{{ entry.dt }}<h6><p>{{ entry.text|safe }}</p><p><{{ entry.id }}</p></li>

        <form action="{{ url_for('delete_entry', entry_id = entry.id) }}" method=post class=delete-entry>
        <input type="hidden" name="entry_id" value="{{ entry.id }}">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </form>

      {% else %}
        <li><em>Unbelievable.  No entries here so far</em></li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endblock %}
```

This is the delete_entry.html:

```
    {% extends "layout.html" %}
    {% block body %}
      <ul class=entries>
      {% for entry in entries %}
        <li><a>{{entry.title }}</a>
        <pre>{{ entry.text }}</pre>
        {% if session.logged_in %}
          <form action="{{ url_for('delete_entry') }}" method=post class=delete-entry>
          <input type=hidden value="{{ entry.id }}"name=movie_to_delete"></input>
          <input type=submit></input>
          </form>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      </ul> 
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, maybe this is in your code, but in case it's not - when you use url_for() you need to have a function in your flask code that represents that route. To clarify, you cannot just have an html template called show_entries, you need a function that renders that template [read about it here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_url_building.htm)

```
@app.route('/show_entries')
def show_entries():
    return render_template('show_entries.html')
```

Also, I think you need to add a GET method to your function to allow for the user to get to the html form where they select whichever entry id they want to delete, like so:

```
@app.route('/delete_entry/<entry_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete_entry():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
        db = get_db()
        db.execute('delete from entries where id=' + entry_id)
        db.commit()
        flash('Entry deleted')
        return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
    else #request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('delete_entry.html')
```